# ADFS, people picker and custom claims provider

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, adfs, claim-provider

I read article of Steve Peshka [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/04/28/how-to-override-the-default-name-resolution-and-claims-provider-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) which points that we have to develop custom claims provider in order to override pepole searching using people picker in SP2010.

I have two questions regarding this approach.

Firstly, If we hook our custom claims provider to trusted identity token issuer, how augmented claims will be encoded? Will it be as they were coming from trusted token issuer (eg. `c:0ǹ.t|adfs|<claimValue>`) or as they would be coming from custom claim provider (eg. `c:0ǹ.c|customclaimprovider|<claimValue>`)?

Secondly, when we attach custom claims provider to token issuer, is there any reference available to that token issuer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your code needs to create the claim, and you specify the original issuer in the constructor. Steve wrote about this too. http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/05/25/replacing-the-out-of-box-name-resolution-in-sharepoint-2010-part-2.aspx
2. The claim provider does not know about the login provider (token issuer). Since you will already have the login provider name (needed to issue the appropriate identity claim), you can get the login provider from the SPSecurityTokenServiceManager